# how to avoid pop up when we try reload or refresh for any frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, frame

There is one frame sometimes which includes to  load action class. But  sometimes due to server issues or some other causes.

In this scenario, I want to reload the script.

But, while reloading the script, I am getting as a pop up like "resending data". and asking  confirmation.

How to avoid pop ups while reloading the script?

Note: As I need to get more than 1KB data(it may extend), I need to use POST request only.
      Will it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to send the post request to server asynchronously, right after the page has been loaded.

In that case, you don't need to refresh your page when there's something wrong. Just simply resend the post request with Javascript. And the browser won't pop up a warning dialog if you refresh the page anyway.

Comment: ok Su27. I think it will work. I will try to implement and update

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you enter the site with a post requset, change it to a get and just "reload it".

Comment: for get request, maximum it can allow 1KB. I may get more data. So I need POST request only. Is there any way to avoid pop up in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server code, and the solution allows it, you can do a redirect to the same url after handling the POST. Then you can do a refresh without POST and confirmation.

Using ajax as suggested by su27 is recommended and a far better solution, but will probably harder to implement...